# Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 installation issues

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to install Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 on Eclipse Juno using the instructions

posted here :

```
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Installing_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse
```

but I am getting the following error :

```
Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.2.3.v201304260926-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.2.3.v201304260926-rel-r37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was using the wrong update link. I should've used :

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 which is the correct update site for Juno.

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 is for Indigo.